# Marking a commit/build for deploy

Tags: teamcity

So we are currently just deploying master but are running into issues where we want to deploy the commit/build in which all our testing was ran on. This is normally a snapshop of master at 4:30pm. We run our build configuation for all tests automatically at 4:30pm (lets call this build config ALLTESTS), so we can control how this commit/build is marked in the ALLTESTS config.

We separate testing and deploy, so when a deploy is executed (either manually or automatically) it should only pick a branch/tag/commit/build that has been marked. Adding the tests to our deploy build config is not a viable solution.

Originally I had planned on using Git tags. A tag called `deploy` would be deleted and added to certain commits and then when the deployment is triggered that commit would be deployed.

The issue I ran into here is that there isnt an easy way to manually add git tags in a build step.  Should I just write command-line build step that uses git commands remove the tag `deploy` from whatever commit has it and to add it to commit that is running?

Is there a better teamcity way to do this?  I have successfully got teamcity tags to work via REST API but I am not sure if those fit the need either.

I suppose I could write powershell to parse the rest API to get the build id that was last successful in ALLTESTS and then feed that into the deploy somehow. How would I go about getting a build number and using that as the basis of deploy?

Comment: why `deploy` is not just a branch in which you merge all commits that should be deployed. in this case you should net delete and re-create this branch...

Comment: Thats a possibility that after the tests run it just creates a branch called deploy from master. I was just thinking teamcity has a more built in process that isnt just calling a bunch of git commands to make a new branch

Comment: You can actually use something like `git tag -f deploy <commit-sha> and have your tag updated to the given commit.

Comment: if you don`t want to make a separate branch for deployments, you can create special file like 'deploy_plan.json' where you can deffine commit #ID to be spread over servers.

Comment: @DarioRodriguez I think that is what I am going to go with, if you want to make a reply ill reward you the bounty

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper I did it before, but I felt that wasn't the answer you were looking for, so I deleted it. Now it's open again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just write command-line build step that uses git commands remove the tag deploy from whatever commit has it and to add it to commit that is running?

Quick answer is no. You can actually use something like this:

`git tag -f deploy <commit-sha>`

And have your tag updated to the given commit.

Cheers.

Comment: Worth noting you have to install git on the build agent(s): https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Git#Git-Gitexecutableontheagent

Which I was hoping would be as simple as installing git on the build server but it wasnt.